# UTF8 encoding issue?

Tags: java, utf-8

I'm calling a service which errors, telling me there is an encoding problem with the below String:

> Universal®

It is my understanding that this String is "utf8" encoded. Is this a correct understanding of utf8 encoding? If so, does this indicate that I should remove the utf8 encoding? If so, any suggestions on how I can de-encode a utf8 String in Java?

Or am I wrong, and the above String is not utf8 encoded? If so, any suggestions how to encode it?

Comment: "an encoding problem" - can you be more specific? Is it not displayed properly, or has it given you a particular error?

Comment: Sorry, that is part of my issue, the error I receive is precisely that vague. It says "Encoding problem". Which is why I'm wondering if it's implying that I'm utf8 encoded when I shouldn't be, or that I'm not utf8 encoded and I should be.

Comment: "calling a service"  - how? SOAP? java method call?

Comment: In the context of a Java `String` object, internally the `String` is*not* encoded in UTF-8.  It is encoded in UTF-16.  That's largely irrelevant, though: the issue is all about how you *transfer* the string data to the service you are trying to call, and about how that service expects you to do so.  Apparently those are mismatched.

Comment: @blank REST service from Java library.

Comment: So HTTP. Are you setting the content-type charset encoding? See my answer.

Comment: Looking at the rendered output of a string doesn't tell anything. It's the underlying binary values that make sense. [Joel on Software's
The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How Java stores the string isn't the same as how it is encoded in messages. You can try something like:

```
String s = "Universal®";
byte[] encoded = s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

You'll have to catch the `UnsupportedCharsetException`, but UTF-8 is a standard available charset.

Or you may need to set the encoding in the sending API, like in HTTP `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: For Java 7+, you can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`

Comment: @Andreas Sweet! I hadn't caught that change. Now I don't have to get annoyed at  useless boilerplate try/catch to get the UTF-8 charset. :)

Answer (score 2):

"Universal®" with `®` U+00AE cannot be represented in plain 7-bits ASCII, Though it can in several other charsets/encodings. The universal Unicode encoding `UTF-8` can mix any script.

You need the text converted as **bytes** in some **encoding** to be able to state its encoding.

In java String is Unicode internally and can deal with everything.

As the java source encoding is free however, it must be the same encoding as used by the java compiler javac. You can however use the u-escaping, using ASCII to represent the special symbols (in the UTF-16 range):

```
String s = "Universal\u00AE";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String t = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
assert t.equals(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

In a very general sense, encoding is just the assortment and allocation of bits, that is used to represent strings. See the link below for more detailed information. Generally all encoding types are fairly transferrable to each other, but there is a few exceptions to this. You have probably seen the large blank squares/etc that mark a symbol that cannot be displayed. This is generally caused by an encoding error (such as the character not existing for that encoding scheme).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

As per your specific problem, that string listed should be UTF-8 Encodable. It may have been saved in another encoding type (which may cause your issue). You could always attempt to convert it to UTF-8 and see what happens.

**Edit**
- In regards to the comments, I expect the issue is related to not encoding it properly before attempting to transfer it via the service (or to the service).

Comment: Everything you say is true, but this doesn't seem to actually answer the question very well.

Answer (score -2):

A quick look  here: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ (and we should know that without looking, people) shows that @ is indeed a utf8 character. So, dunno what framework complains about it not being such, but it's wrong

Comment: That @ should be ®, however it is still available for UTF-8 (Registered Sign I think)

Comment: UTF-8 is an *encoding*.  Yes, it can encode the character ®, but that has no bearing on whether a particular byte sequence encoding that character in fact employs UTF-8, as opposed to any of the several alternatives.